# Bind datagrid to an ObservableCollection list

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new with WPF and I would like to bind from xaml to an ObservableCollection. Currently I am doing like this:

in xaml:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <local:ProcessingStep DataContext="{Binding ProcessingSteps[0]}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
<Grid Grid.Column="2">
<local:ProcessingStep DataContext="{Binding ProcessingSteps[1]}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
<Grid Grid.Column="3">
     <local:ProcessingStep DataContext="{Binding ProcessingSteps[2]}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

in cs:

```
public ObservableCollection<ProcessingStepView> ProcessingSteps
{
     get
     {
        return m_ProcessingSteps ??
             (m_ProcessingSteps = new ObservableCollection<ProcessingStepViewl>
                       {
                           new ProcessingStepView("Step1"),
                           new ProcessingStepView("Step2"),
                           new ProcessingStepView("Step3")
                       });
      }
}
```

How can I bind the list directly to wpf? e.g: if I have 100 steps, it is not nice to do one by one.

Comment: How do you arrange items in columns? Do they have same width or the aim is just to stack them horizontally?

Comment: I would like to stack them horizontally

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) with `ItemTemplate` and bind your list:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ProcessingSteps}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:ProcessingStep />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

`ItemsControl` is basically just a repeater, without selection, that will repeat `ItemTemplate` as many times as many items there are in `ProcessingSteps` and place them in whichever panel you choose. In this case horizontal `StackPanel`

Comment: No problem @olidev. BTW if you won't provide `ItemsPanel` by default it will use vertical `StackPanel` but you can change it to any `Panel` you want like `Grid`, `WrapPanel`, `Canvas` or `UniformGrid`. Every list control inherits from `ItemsControl`, for example `ListBox` is `ItemsControl` with item selection functionality added on top but the mechanism stays the same